# Using TFS API to fetch All Priority Triage Severity values

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfs-sdk

I am building a Web Application using TFS API. I would like to fetch the All the range of "Priority" values from the TFS API and populate my asp.net dropdownlist. Similarly. I would like to fetch All the for `"Severity" and "Triage" and populate them into different dropdownlist.

I have an image of what I am talking about below :

[image]

Here is the code I have to access TFS Projects so far 
Can anyone let me know who I can access all the ITEMS TFS has for Priority, Severity & Triage :

```
Uri url = new Uri("server location");
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(credentials, url);
TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, nc);
coll.EnsureAuthenticated();
WorkItemStore workItemStore = coll.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
workItemStore.FieldDefinitions["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"].AllowedValues
```

or

```
var filters = new FieldFilterList();
filters.Add(new FieldFilter(CoreField.State, "New"));
workItemStore.FieldDefinitions["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"].FilteredAllowedValues(filters);
```

should work. Using the first or second example depends if you want *all* admitted values or just those admitted in a specific state; you can set even more complex filters.

Substitute `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority` with the other fields you are interested in, the Reference names can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983994.aspx).